# Searching the string in a text sitting on 1 coulmn

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010, vba, macros

I'm very new into VBA coding, I would like to have some assistance as I have been trying for two days, I have got data fixed in column A, I would like to search for a string in that column, eg Statement date, if found extract the date and create a new column in the next sheet2, Place Statement date as a header and 01/01/2008 as detail, append the next occurrence if found. Here is my newbie piece of code.

```
Sub testing44()
 Dim intPasteRow As Integer
    intPasteRow = 1
    Dim intRow As Integer
    Dim Found As Range, FirstFound As String


Sheets("Sheet1").Select
Columns("B:B").Select
On Error Resume Next
Selection.Find(What:="STATEMENT DATE *", After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:= _
    xlFormulas, LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:= _
    xlNext, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False).Activate

If Err.Number = 91 Then
    MsgBox "ERROR: 'STATEMENT DATE:' could not be found."
    End
End If


On Error Resume Next
Selection.Find(What:="INITIAL MARGIN", After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:= _
    xlFormulas, LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:= _
    xlNext, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False).Activate

If Err.Number = 91 Then
    MsgBox "ERROR: 'INITIAL MARGIN' could not be found."
    End
End If


intRow = ActiveCell.Row
Rows(intRow & ":" & intRow).Select
Selection.Copy

Sheets("Sheet2").Select
Range("A" & intPasteRow).Select
ActiveSheet.Paste

Sheets("Sheet2").Select
Rows(intRow + 1 & ":" & intRow).Select
End Sub
```

Comment: Could you please explain in more what your data looks like, and what you're trying to achieve? Maybe you could add sample input/output to your question?

Comment: What errors are you running into?

Answer (score 0):

Its not exactly clear on what you are trying to do, but based on what you've told us so far, I have some specific suggestions:

In creating new sheets from existing data, I generally 'step' thru the initial data in a loop, looking for characteristics I'm interested in, then copying the entire row (or particular cells I'm interested in) to the new sheet one row at a time. What's not clear to me, is how many new sheets will your program create? If more than two, I suggest you rethink the exercise.

--this makes your software much simpler to implement

--consider creating a SINGLE output sheet. Add a column for "statement date", then utilize the "filter - autofilter" choice to let your end users select for themselves what's what.

It's easiest if data starts as rows, do the macro, create rows as output. I will say, what does make this copying thing a bit tricky is if original individual data entry fields are in string format or number format.

If you insist on a new sheet for each "statement date" and you need column data, then as last step in your macro, transpose the row(s) to a columns(s)